# Twitter conversion not working when Adblock is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am using the first code snippet in https://business.twitter.com/en/solutions/twitter-ads/website-clicks/advanced-conversion-tracking.html to track. The problem is that when AdBlock Plus is enabled, this throws an error.

Is there some way to get around this?

[image]

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you by any chance?

Comment: @LucaKiebel no, I still have the same, sorry for late answer

Comment: Are you still encountering the same error?

Comment: @LucaKiebel yes I am

Comment: I edited my answer, I just confirmed in a JSFiddle that this doesn't produce an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the script loaded (e.g. if the type of the variable named `twttr` is not `undefined`) before executing the script:

```html
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/oct.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

if(typeof twttr !== 'undefined')twttr.conversion.trackPid('163yb', {tw_sale_amount: AMOUNT_HERE, tw_order_quantity: QUANTITY_HERE });

</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt=" " src="https://analytics.twitter.com/i/adsct?txn_id=163yb&p_id=Twitter$tw_sale_amount=AMOUNT_HERE&tw_order_quantity=QUANTITY_HERE" />
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt=" " src="//tdotco/i/adsct?txn_id=163yb&p_id=Twitter$tw_sale_amount=0&tw_order_quantity=0" />
</noscript>
```